# Simple jquery and php problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? any help would be appreciated.

This is the HTML

```
Enter Code:<br/><input type="text" name="code" id="code"/><br/> 
<input type="button" id="confirm" value="Confirm" onClick="confirm()"/>
```

This is the PHP *(basically gets the value of the user input and if it's equal to the variable a echo sucess)*

```
$code = $_POST["code"]; 
$a = 105678; 
if($code==$a){ 
  echo "sucess"; 
} else { 
  echo "nosucces"; 
}
```

The JavaScript *(simple ajax code to alert yay on PHP sucess or nay on no sucess)*

```
function confirm () { 
  $.post(
    "confirm.php",
    {code:$(this).val() },
    function(data) { 
      if(data=='sucess') { 
        alert("yay"); 
      } else { 
        alert("nay");
      } 
    }
  ); 
}
```

basically on all occasions the ouput is nay on further debugging i tried an elseif statement on the javascript asking if data is equal to nosucces but it didn't even alert anything, meaning it's not getting the data from the php

Comment: Please when asking a programming question, *never* describe the problem as "doesn't work". Please describe exactly what goes wrong how, and what errors you get in the browser console (if any). Thanks!

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: what you are geting now?

Comment: @Tommy: Pro tip: Put more effort into formatting your code.

Comment: Hi, sorry i'm new here and this is my first time asking a question..

Comment: basically on all occasions the ouput is nay on further debugging i tried an elseif statement on the javascript asking if data is equal to nosucces but it didn't even alert anything, meaning it's not getting the data from the php..

Comment: btw this is just a small scale of what i'm currently doing..

Comment: @Tomalak: what do you mean by formatting?

Answer (score 3):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#confirm').click(function() {
        $.post("",{code:$('#code').val() } ,function(data)
        {
            if(data=='sucess')
            {
                alert("yay");
            }
            else
            {alert("nay");}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, it works, the funny thing is i used the document.ready before and it didn't work. thanks very much though..

Answer (score 0):

Give brackets at end, so that it does understand that you are calling a function, also don't use `confirm` as function name, its a native JS function, use `my_confirm` instead.

```
onClick="my_confirm()"
```

Also `$(this).val()` won't work in your case use `$('#code').val()` instead.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo, i added the () in the real one and have tried my_confirm..

Comment: Thank you too for helping,I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#confirm').click(function() {
       $.ajax({
         url: "confirm.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: "code="+$('input[name="code"]').val(),
         dataType: "text",
         async:false,
         success: function(msg){
           if(msg=='sucess'){
             alert('yay');
           }else{
             alert('nay');
           }
         }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you and keep it up dude